# Virtual TableViewer sorting causes selection problems

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, tableviewer

Our application is an RCP appliction and needs to display table of several thousands items. For this reason, we're using `SWT.VIRTUAL` in our `TableViewer`. That works pretty well except for selection.

We're having following issue :

- Our `TableViewer` support sorting and filtering. When we use a virtual tableviewer, changing the selection does not preserve the current selected item but the row currently selected.This leads to another item being selected.
  e.g: If Item 'A' present at the 5th row is selected by user and sorting is performed, then after sorting the Item at the 5th row gets selected instead of the Item 'A'.
  Using a non virtual `TableViewer`, everything works fine.

We tried to go into debug and found out that the cache from the `AbstractTableViewer.VirtualManager` class seems to be up to date with the model.
Forcing the cache to be used in the `AbstractTableViewer.virtualSetSelectionToWidget()` can be a possible approach.

We have tried to implement a solution suggested in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=338696. However it didn't work.

Please suggest some pointers or alternative work around.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Adding the part of your code regarding your need would help people to reply back with apt answers!

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround for working with huge tables I would suggest you to take a look at the Nattable project http://www.eclipse.org/nattable/. It supports everything you need (sorting, filtering, tree structured elements, lazy loading etc.). We successfully use it in our project, where it is necessary to display hundreds of thousands elements as a tree with around 160 columns. It also has some pretty cool styling features, which can make your table more user-friendly and interactive. Hope this helps